# default project page for laravel in main page instead of React

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Hope you can help with this issue:

I am trying to host my website online, the problem is that the whole web(spa) is made in React, I only have a contact form in laravel, however, when i load my backend using laravel into the hosting folders instead of the react website I see the default laravel web, I changed my .htaccess to the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule . /index.html$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

but still not showing the web, only the default laravel welcome page.
on my public_html folder I have the content of my laravel backend public folder, and the build files of the react, on the root folder the rest of the backend-laravel project,
attached screenshot of the files[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe index.php file causes this situation. You can test it by changing index.php file name.

Comment: it was the issue, now the react part is showing but I have another problem :), when i submit the form I get 404 error

Comment: it means that if I change the name of index,php the baceknd does not work but If I dont do it, frontend does not work